# Exception line number in CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm evaluating an script using the `CSharpScript.EvaluatyAsync<T>` method and passing some C# code.
I can easily see the line number of errors when there is a parsing issue, e.g. a syntax error, but when there is a runtime exception all I get is an `AggregateException` wrapping my exception (`NullReferenceException`) in this case, but there is no clue of how to get the line number for me (3 in this example below).

```
Console.WriteLine(CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(
    @"string s = null; 
// some comment at line 2
var upper = s.ToUpper(); // Null reference exception at line 3
// more code").Result);
```

EDIT:

I've been researching this and found that the Scripting API creates an assembly without pdb information [here line 127](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting/ScriptBuilder.cs,d25524edca91053f,references) so this will be impossible to know where the exception happened. Am I right?

Comment: [My trivial attempt at fixing the code you pointed to](https://github.com/svick/roslyn/commit/5030b3cce03e57ab4d5a36eb1d113ba2d36f7c9b) didn't change anything, so I suggest you file this as an issue at the Roslyn repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some version of CSharpScript the team added a solution: now you can add `ScriptOptions.Default.WithEmitDebugInformation(true)` to the `EvaluateAsync` method.

See my test cases below on how to extract the exception line number:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LineNumberInStackTrace()
{
    try
    {
        var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(
            @"string s = null; 
// some comment at line 2
var upper = s.ToUpper(); // Null reference exception at line 3
// more code", ScriptOptions.Default.WithEmitDebugInformation(true)).Result;

    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        if (e.InnerException is NullReferenceException inner)
        {
            var startIndex = inner.StackTrace.IndexOf(":line ", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 6;
            var lineNumberStr = inner.StackTrace.Substring(
                startIndex, inner.StackTrace.IndexOf("\r", StringComparison.Ordinal) - startIndex);
            var lineNumber = Int32.Parse(lineNumberStr);

            Assert.AreEqual(3, lineNumber);
            return;
        }
    }
    Assert.Fail();
}
[TestMethod]
public void LineNumberNotInStackTrace()
{
    try
    {
        var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<int>(
            @"string s = null; 
// some comment at line 2
var upper = s.ToUpper(); // Null reference exception at line 3
// more code").Result;

    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        if (e.InnerException is NullReferenceException inner)
        {
            var startIndex = inner.StackTrace.IndexOf(":line ", StringComparison.Ordinal);

            Assert.AreEqual(-1, startIndex);
            return;
        }
    }
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance, you'll probably want to look at the information inside of the `AggregateException.InnerExceptions` property.

Comment: I don't see any line number information in the `NullReferenceException` that's the `InnerException`.